# Dual of a Comma Category

Tags: category-theory, slice-category

Let $F:\mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be a functor between two categories and $d$ be an object of  $\mathcal{D}$. Does the following hold:

$(F \downarrow d)^{op} \cong (d \downarrow F^{op})$

If yes, how can I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The objects of $(F\downarrow d)$ as well as its opposite
are pairs $(c,f)$ where $f:Fc\to d$ is an arrow in $\mathcal{D}$.

The objects of $(d\downarrow F^{op})$ are pairs $(c,g)$ where $g:d\to Fc$
is an arrow in $\mathcal{D}$. There's no natural way to pair off these two different classes of objects.

Comment: A silly example to illustrate it: $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{D}=(\mathrm{Set})$, $F$ the identity, $d=\emptyset$.

Comment: I would have thought that an object in $(d\downarrow F^{op})$ is a pair $(c,g)$ where $g: d\to F(c)$ is an arrow in $\mathcal{D}^{op}$, and hence $(F\downarrow d)^{op} = (d\downarrow F^{op})$.